# Find the minimum element in a sorted and rotated array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, data-structures, binary-search

The question:
A sorted array A[ ] with distinct elements is rotated at some unknown point, the task is to find the minimum element in it.

Expected Time Complexity: O(Log n)

 My code:

```
def binarySearch(arr, n): 
    s = 0
    e = n-1
    while e >= s: 
        mid = (s+e) // 2
        if e==s:
            return arr[e]
        if mid == s and arr[mid] < arr[mid+1]:
            return arr[mid]
        elif mid == e and arr[mid] < arr[mid-1]:
            return arr[mid]
        elif arr[mid] < arr[mid - 1] and arr[mid] < arr[mid+1]:
            return arr[mid]
        elif arr[mid] < arr[e]:
            e = mid - 1
        else:
            e = mid + 1
```

When I use the Array = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 5, 7], I get the answer = 10, whereas, it should be 5. 
What could the error be? 
EDIT: Following the answer, I also had to add the following line to consider one case that's left

```
if e==s:
    return arr[e]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this involve just a normal binary search?

```py
def binarySearch(arr, n): 
    s = 0
    e = n-1
    while e >= s: 
        mid = (s+e) // 2
        if e == s:
            return arr[e]
        elif mid == s and arr[mid] < arr[mid+1]:
            return arr[mid]
        elif mid == e and arr[mid] < arr[mid-1]:
            return arr[mid]
        elif arr[mid] < arr[mid - 1] and arr[mid] < arr[mid+1]:
            return arr[mid]
        elif arr[mid] < arr[e]:
            e = mid - 1
        else:
            s = mid + 1
```

I think your last line should be `s = mid + 1` instead of `e = mid + 1`.